# Simulate a quantum computer on a normal one

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

Would it be possible to simulate a quantum computer on a normal computer. I was thinking something like have a bunch of GPU's running a set of entangled quantum particles and then produce the results. Would this be feasible or one of those take the lifetime of the universe to run problems?

Comment: Related: [Are there emulators for quantum computers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12/99)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is definitely possible to simulate a quantum computer on a classical one, but as you point out the real question is whether it can be done efficiently.

The calculations a quantum computer is doing are *not* fancy mathematics: it is all linear algebra in terms of unitary evolution and projective measurement of a finite-dimensional quantum system. However, if you have $n$ qubits the dimension of the state space rises as $2^n$ so that you very soon have unmanageably large matrices, and even efficient linear algebraic algorithms (in terms of matrix size) become exponentially-scaling ones.

There are a number of known quantum-computational algorithms that can be efficiently simulated with a classical computer (take for example the [Gottesman-Knill theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gottesman%E2%80%93Knill_theorem)) and it is an ongoing research area as to which calculations can and cannot be thus simulated. If (as appears to be the case) factoring cannot be efficiently done on a classical computer, then Shor's algorithm is an example of the latter.