# Limitations of Quantum Simulations on a Classical Computer

Tags: computational-physics, quantum-computer, anyons

My question is on the simulation of a quantum computer on a classical machine. I understand that a classical computer to simulate any quantum algorithm--the problem is that the quantum computer does its calculations much more efficiently than the classical computer can. This problem is addressed here:

[simulate a quantum computer on a normal one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29307/simulate-a-quantum-computer-on-a-normal-one)

However, my question is why can't a classical computer simulate a quantum many-body system which can then be used to simulate a quantum computer? For example, why can't we use a dynamical 2D density matrix [density matrix renormalization group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix_renormalization_group) (DMRG) or some similar computational method to simulate anyonic braiding which can then be used to construct a quantum computer? Is it because DMRG and similar numerically variational techniques aren't truly quantum simulations, and thus there would be no real gain in efficiency?

Comment: I'm no expert on Quantum Computing, but my guess is that simulating quantum many-body system can be incredibly expensive, and, thus, it's going to be inneficient to use a n-body simulation to, in turn, simulate a quantum computer.

Comment: DMRG simulations of time evolution are limited by the growth of entropy, which will always appear when simulating quantum computation. Other simulation methods have other limitations when simulating quantum computations.